# Чертвертое управление: строчная или прописная?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с какой буквы писать "четвертое управление" — речь идет о КГБ или к чему оно относилось при СССР.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно подобные учреждения пишут через цифру "4-е управление". Если всё-таки писать прописью, то "Четвёртое управление"

Comment: Да нет, это как имя собственное, цифирью обычно не пишут.
А заглавная - да.